# Spring : Display Eureka Services as down instead of removing

Tags: spring, yaml, netflix-eureka

I have a `Eureka Server` and have numerous clients. Now whenever any service gets registered it gets displayed on `Eureka Page`. When i kill a particular service now i want to still display it on the page with the status as down. But what is happening in my case is that speicific instance does not get displayed. Can anyone please help.

Server - Yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka

server:
  port: 4544
  context-path: /eureka

eureka:
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
    eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 1000
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:4544/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    homePageUrlPath: /eureka/

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Client - YML

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myclient

server:
  port: 3333
  context-path: /myclient

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    lease:
      duration: 5
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:4544/eureka/
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    hostname: localhost
    homePageUrlPath: /myclient/
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Let us assume, it is possible to do this. Consider the scenario where you ahve 20 service, of which you have killed 15. now you have 15 services will status as DOWN. Now, if you want to delete a few of these 15 which are not relevant. How would you do it?

Comment: @pvpkiran : I mean i have seen in few applications that they show the instance as down and not remove them.

Comment: Eureka shows instances as "Down" when their health actuator reports down as a status. This should be the case if the instance can not operate because e.g. some external requirement is not fulfilled. But that is something different than beeing shut down.